# Python Selenium drag and drop hangs until I move the cursor manually

Tags: python, selenium

Hi I am getting a problem when I automate drag and drop hangs until I move the cursor manually below is my code. I am new to automation testing. I'd appreciate your help, thank you.

```
def drag_element(self):
    self.element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath')
    try:
        self.logger.debug("\nAtempting to perform drag and drop")
        self.action_chains = ActionChains(self.driver)
        self.action_chains.drag_and_drop_by_offset(self.element,1,1).perform()

        return True
    except NoSuchElementException:
        self.auto_log("error", "Element {} does not exist".format(self.element))
        return None
```

Comment: Note that `self.element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath')` is outside of `try` block, so `except NoSuchElementException` is useless in this case  as it won't catch the exception if `element` not found

Comment: Hi Anderson, thank you for the response. Noted.